# Is it hard to evaluate $\int \frac{x^{3}+1}{x^{6}+1} d x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{x^{3}+1}{x^{6}+1} &=\frac{x\left(x^{2}+1\right)-(x-1)}{x^{6}+1} =\frac{x}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1}-\frac{x-1}{x^{6}+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore

$$
\int \frac{x^{3}+1}{x^{6}+1} d x=\underbrace{\int \frac{x d x}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1}}_{H}-\underbrace{\int \frac{x-1}{x^{6}+1} d x}_{M}
$$

Let’s start with the easier one $H$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
H &=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d y}{y^{2}-y+1}=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d y}{\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{3}{4}} \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+c_{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+c_1
\end{aligned}
$$
For the harder one $M $, we first split the integrand into 2 and then 3.

Let $$\frac{x-1}{x^{6}+1} \equiv \frac{A x+B}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{f(x)}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1} $$
for some constant $A, B$ and cubic polynomial $f(x).$

Then comparing their numerator yields

$$x-1 \equiv(A x+B)\left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)+\left(x^{2}+1\right) f(x)$$

Putting $ x =i $ yields

$ \begin{aligned}i-1 & = (A i+B)(1+1+1) \\&=3 A i+3 B \\ A &=\frac{1}{3} \text { and } B=-\frac{1}{3} \\\left(x^{2}+1\right) f(x) &=x-1-\frac{1}{3}(x-1)\left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right) \\f(x) &=-\frac{(x-1)\left(x^{2}-2\right)}{3}\end{aligned} \tag*{} $

Putting them back to the integral gives

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\int \frac{x-1}{x^{6}+1} d x&=\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{x-1}{x^{2}+1} d x-\frac{1}{3} \int \frac{(x-1)\left(x^{2}-2\right)}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1} d x\\&=\frac{1}{3}\left[\underbrace{\int\frac{x-1}{x^{2}+1}-d x}_{J}-\underbrace{\int \frac{x\left(x^{2}-2\right)}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1}}_{K} d x+\underbrace{\int \frac{x^{2}-2}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1}}_{L} d x\right]\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

We first start split the integral $J$ into two and get
$\displaystyle J=\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(x^{2}+1\right)-\tan ^{-1} x+c_{2}\tag*{} $

For the integral $ K$ , letting $ y=x^2$ yields

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}K &=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{y-2}{y^{2}-y+1} d y \\&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\frac{1}{2}(2 y-1)-\frac{3}{2}}{y^{2}-y+1} d y \\&=\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{d\left(y^{2}-y+1\right)}{y^{2}-y+1}-\frac{3}{4} \int \frac{d y}{\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{3}{4}} \\&=\frac{1}{4} \ln \left(x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right)-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+c_{3}\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

For the integral $L $, let’s play a little trick on the integrand and get

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}L &=\int \frac{x^{2}-2}{x^{4}-x^{2}+1} d x \\&=\int \frac{1-\frac{2}{x^{2}}}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1} d x \\&=\int \frac{-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)+\frac{3}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)}{x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}-1} d x\\&=-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}+1}+\frac{3}{2} \int \frac{d\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{2}-3}\\&=-\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \ln \left|\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}-\sqrt{3}}{x+\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{3}}\right|+c_{4}\end{aligned}\tag*{} $

Putting them together concludes that

$\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{12}\left[-2 \ln \left(x^{2}+1\right)+4 \tan ^{-1} x+\ln \left|x^{4}-x^{2}+1\right|-\frac{5\sqrt3}{3}  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x^{2}-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\sqrt{3} \ln \left|\frac{x^{2}-\sqrt{3} x+1}{x^{2}+\sqrt{3} x+1}\right|\right]+C \tag*{} $

**Your comments and alternate solutions are highly appreciated.**

Comment: So is your question just whether there's a shorter route to that antiderivative? (The shortest proof of its correctness is to differentiate it, but you probably want an approach that finds it, not one that merely verifies it.)

Comment: You are right! I just want to know whether there are simpler methods.

Comment: You can actually factor $x^4-x^2+1$ into factors of the form $x^2\pm \sqrt{3}x+1$.  This lets you do a nicer partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @xpaul, you are right.  Thank you very much for catching what I missed.  Fixed now.

Comment: The only way faster would be to use a tool like Mathematica...

Answer (score 4):

I think that playing withe the roots of unity is faster.

$$\frac{x^3+1}{x^6+1}=\frac{1+i}{-6 x+6 i}-\frac{1-i}{6 x+6 i}+\frac{1+i}{6-3 \left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) x}+$$ $$\frac{1-i}{6+3 \left(\sqrt{3}-i\right) x}+\frac{1+i}{6+3 \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) x}-\frac{1-i}{-6+3 \left(\sqrt{3}+i\right) x}$$ leads to the sum of six logarithms to be recombined as three logarithms and three arctangents.

Comment: I like this one.   And it works in the case $x$ is a complex variable, unlike the ones with $\log|\dots|$ in them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach via symmetry. Let
$$I=\int\frac{1+x^3}{1+x^6}dx\>\> \>\>\>\>\>J=\int\frac{x+x^4}{1+x^6}dx$$
Then, show that
\begin{align}
I-J
=&\ \frac1{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3x}{1+x^2}+\frac12\ln\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+x^6}}{1+x^2}\\
I+J
=&\ \frac23\tan^{-1}x+\frac13\tan^{-1}\frac x{1-x^2}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}{1-2x^2}\\
\end{align}